# network login vs. network cable

Tags: networking, login, restart

I disconnected network cable to .... move it. when I reconnect it the whole system had problem with it. I was not able to execute console or log in(on ctrl+shift+fx consoles). after some time 20 consoles (gnome-terminal) did open. however I still have no internet.

P.S. I do not have root account

how can I restart network card? do I need to restart system?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you were not able to connect to other tty's, but it sounds like your network needs to reestablish an IP address from your router or modem. If your using Network Manager, you should just be able to click the Wired connection, however, (this may not work without root permissions) you could run the command **dhcpcd eth0** (or the approperate wired interface) and it'll get you connected again. Simple restart should do the trick if all else fails.